# Getting error when passing parameters from Where block in Groovy-Spock code

Tags: groovy, where-clause, spock

I have written a code for my application.

```
def "Test for file type #FileFormat"() {
      given:
      HttpURLConnection connection = getHandlerURL('endpoint')
      connection.setDoOutput(true)
      connection.setRequestMethod("POST")
      connection.setRequestProperty(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "RdfFormat."+RDFFileFormat+".toMIME()")
      rdfStatement = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel().read(new ByteArrayInputStream(readRDFfromfile(Filename).bytes), null, "RdfFormat."+RDFFileFormat.toString()).listStatements().nextStatement()

      when:
      connection.getOutputStream().write(readRDFfromfile(Filename).bytes)

      then:
      connection.getResponseCode() == HTTP_CREATED


      where:
      FileFormat      | Filename           | RDFFileFormat
      'N-TRIPLES'     | 'n-triples.nt'     | "NTRIPLES"
}
```

When I run my code I am getting error: `SampleTest.Test for file type #FileFormat:37 » Riot` in last line of Given clause.

The test is passing if I use `RdfFormat.NTRIPLES.toString()` instead of using the parameter *RDFFileFormat* passed from Where clause.

Tried assigning `def format1 = "RdfFormat."+RDFFileFormat+".toString()"` and using *format1*, but got same error.

Is there any way I can make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably want:

```
connection.setRequestProperty(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, RdfFormat."$RDFFileFormat".toMIME())
```